# Is it possible to remove an existing registration from Autofac container builder?

Tags: c#, autofac

Something along those lines:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyType>().As<IType>();
builder.RegisterType<MyType2>().As<IType>();
builder.DeRegisterType<MyType>().As<IType>()

var container = builder.Build();
var types = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IType>>();
Assert.IsTrue(types.Count == 1);
Assert.IsTrue(types[0].GetType == typeof(MyType2));
```

Scenario: I go through bunch of assemblies and as I go I register types but I want to
make sure that I have only one implementation of a given type. I need to do this before I create the container. I could track that on my own but it would be nice if Autofac could help me a bit.

Comment: I have another reason for wanting this: Using RegisterAssemblyTypes I get a default 'background' of `InstancePerDependencyScope` resolutions. After this I want to upgrade some of them to `InstancePerLifetimeScope`. This works fine by re-registering them until such point as I resolve an enumerable of some interface (e.g. one that's implemented on more than one class). Removing the 'background' registration would allow this.

Comment: For my particular issue I discovered `RegisterAssemblyTypes().Except<TypeForUpgrading>()` and other fluent methods that can control the selection and treatment of assembly types being registered.

Answer (score 16):

This cannot be done directly using the `ContainerBuilder`, unless you start over with a new one. Mind you, having first built a container you should be able to construct a new container filtering away unwanted types and reusing the registrations from the first container. Like this:

```
...
var container = builder.Build();

builder = new ContainerBuilder();
var components = container.ComponentRegistry.Registrations
                    .Where(cr => cr.Activator.LimitType != typeof(LifetimeScope))
                    .Where(cr => cr.Activator.LimitType != typeof(MyType));
foreach (var c in components)
{
    builder.RegisterComponent(c);
}

foreach (var source in container.ComponentRegistry.Sources)
{
    cb.RegisterSource(source);
}

container = builder.Build();
```

This is hardly very elegant but it works. Now, if you could elaborate on **why** you want to do this, perhaps there is a better way.

Comment: Clever idea. You'd also need to copy the RegistrationSources property across, but this would work.

Comment: @Nicholas - there, added copying the sources. Also, not sure what implications it had, but I ended up with duplicates of the `LifetimeScope` component. So filtering out that one too.

Comment: @Nicholas Blumhardt, could you please explain why do we need it? register/resolve functionality works without second foreach

Comment: Is there a bug in this? What is 'c' in the line
foreach (var source in c.ComponentRegistry.Sources)

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt I ran across this question looking for a solution to an issue I'm facing with decorators (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52611948/can-an-autofac-decorator-be-registered-to-override-existing-registrations).  Replacing the registrations probably isn't the answer, but it's a case where it would come in handy to be able to do so.  The better solution in my case would be if decorator registrations  overrode existing registrations like other components.

Comment: Late to the party; I just want to provide motivation. We are running tests on our API, which uses AutoFac for dependencies. We, however, would like to override the dependencies for some of our IO-dependent services. This is easy to do when you have a simple flat dependency, however, we have a composite that we want to remove. This is, for instance, more difficult. similarly, when utilizing decorators a similar issue arises.

Answer (score 1):

Peter L.'s probably got the most straightforward option.

To get around the problem altogether, can you modify the way you're discovering components to filter them in advance of registration? It does seem like there must be an approach that gets around this... It also might be a challenge further down the track to work out which components to keep vs. which to remove.

A more involved approach is to override `IEnumerable` support to filter out the the things you don't want. I.e. copy and modify this code to create a `FilteredCollectionSource` that excludes the components you don't want.

```
var elements = c.ComponentRegistry.RegistrationsFor(elementTypeService);
```

would become:

```
var elements = c.ComponentRegistry.RegistrationsFor(elementTypeService)
    .Where(reg => /* not a duplicate */);
```

If you add your `FilteredCollectionSource` to the builder using `RegisterSource()` it will should get used instead of the built-in one.

Comment: Unfortunately I get components in batches and the number of batches is unknown. Thanks for help