# Autofac unregister all implementations of interface

Tags: autofac

Is it possible to unregister all implementations of an interface in Autofac?

My scenario:

I register two modules, one DefaultModule and later a SpecificModule if some conditions are fulfilled.

```
builder.RegisterModule(new DefaultModule());

if (someCondition)
{
   builder.RegisterModule(new SpecificModule());
}
```

The two modules register multiple named instances of an interface, let's call it ISomething.

Inside the Load function in DefaultModule:

```
builder.RegisterType<DefaultSomething1>().Named<ISomething>("DefaultSomething1").SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<DefaultSomething2>().Named<ISomething>("DefaultSomething2").SingleInstance();
```

Inside the Load function in SpecificModule:

```
builder.RegisterType<SpecificSomething1>().Named<ISomething>("SpecificSomething1").SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<SpecificSomething2>().Named<ISomething>("SpecificSomething2").SingleInstance();
```

When I register the SpecificModule I want to unregister all previous registrations of ISomething since they are injected as a collection into another constructor.

```
public SomeClass(IEnumerable<ISomething> somethingCollection)
{
   _somethingCollection = somethingCollection;
}
```

Is this possible? Or is it better to do it in another way?

Answer (score 0):

It should atleast be possible to create a new container with the unwanted components filtered out, see
[Is it possible to remove an existing registration from Autofac container builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091101/is-it-possible-to-remove-an-existing-registration-from-autofac-container-builder)