# Autofac: cannot resolve dependency using factory after ContainerBuilder.Update()

Tags: autofac

My problem is that I want to use *Func<> factory* to resolve dependency. And in if I use *ContainerBuilder Update()* (I need it for mocking some services in integration tests), this factories still resolve outdated instances.

I created simple scenario to reproduce the problem:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<Test>().As<ITest>();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<Test1Factory>().As<ITestFactory>();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<TestConsumer>().AsSelf();
        var container = containerBuilder.Build();

        var tc1 = container.Resolve<TestConsumer>();

        var cbupdater = new ContainerBuilder();
        cbupdater.RegisterType<Test2>().As<ITest>();
        cbupdater.RegisterType<Test2Factory>().As<ITestFactory>();
        cbupdater.Update(container);

        var tc2 = container.Resolve<TestConsumer>();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public interface ITest
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Test : ITest
{
    public Test()
    {
        Id = 1;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Test2 : ITest
{
    public Test2()
    {
        Id = 2;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface ITestFactory
{
    ITest Create();
}

public class Test1Factory : ITestFactory
{
    public ITest Create()
    {
        return new Test();
    }
}

public class Test2Factory : ITestFactory
{
    public ITest Create()
    {
        return new Test2();
    }
}

public class TestConsumer
{
    public TestConsumer(Func<ITest> testFactory, ITest test, ITestFactory customFactory)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("factory: " + testFactory().Id);
        Console.WriteLine("direct: " + test.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("MyCustomFactory: " + customFactory.Create().Id);
        Console.WriteLine("*************");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

The output is:

> factory: 1 direct: 1 MyCustomFactory: 1
>
> ---
>
> factory: 1 direct: 2 MyCustomFactory: 2
>
> ---

Notice "factory: 1" in both cases.

Am I missing something or I have to create my cusom factory in this scenario?

P.S.

Autofac 3.5.2 or 4.0 beta 8-157
.net 4.5.1

Answer (score 0):

That's by design unfortunately, the reasons, I don't know.  Looking at the Autofac code gives you a better insight on how they register items with the same interface definition, in short, all registrations are maintained but the last registration wins ([ref](http://ask.programmershare.com/288_14009661/)).  Wait...that's not all, weirdly, for *Fun<...>*, you actually get them in order.  You can easily test by changing the constructor of the *TestConsumer* class to:

```
public TestConsumer(Func<ITest> testFactory, IEnumerable<Func<ITest>> testFactories, IEnumerable<ITest> tests, ITest test, ITestFactory customFactory)
{
    // ...
}
```

Note that you get all the Funcs and the ITest registration.  You are simply **lucky** that resolving ITest directly resolves to Test2.

Now, having said all of the above, there is a way [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091101/is-it-possible-to-remove-an-existing-registration-from-autofac-container-builder).  You have to create a container without the registration you want to override, therefore:

```
/// <summary>
/// This has not been tested with all your requirements
/// </summary>
private static IContainer RemoveOldComponents(IContainer container)
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    var components = container.ComponentRegistry.Registrations
                        .Where(cr => cr.Activator.LimitType != typeof(LifetimeScope))
                        .Where(cr => cr.Activator.LimitType != typeof(Func<ITest>));
    foreach (var c in components)
    {
        builder.RegisterComponent(c);
    }

    foreach (var source in container.ComponentRegistry.Sources)
    {
        builder.RegisterSource(source);
    }
    return builder.Build();
}
```

And you can simply change your main method to the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
    containerBuilder.RegisterType<Test>().As<ITest>();
    containerBuilder.RegisterType<Test1Factory>().As<ITestFactory>();
    containerBuilder.RegisterType<TestConsumer>().AsSelf();
    var container = containerBuilder.Build();

    var tc1 = container.Resolve<TestConsumer>();

    container = RemoveOldComponents(container);

    var cbupdater = new ContainerBuilder();
    cbupdater.RegisterType<Test2>().As<ITest>();
    cbupdater.RegisterType<Test2Factory>().As<ITestFactory>();
    cbupdater.Update(container);

    var tc2 = container.Resolve<TestConsumer>();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

PS: Wouldn't it be great to have a method which does the exact opposite of *PreserveExistingDefaults()*