# Can an Autofac Decorator be registered to override existing registrations?

Tags: autofac

Given multiple types are registered with the same interface, Autofac uses the last type registered when resolving a component.

An exception to this behavior seems to be with Autofac's decorator feature.  Given a type is registered as IDoSomething either before or after the type is decorated using the standard process of registering a keyed type and then registering a decorator with the same key, it seems the instance returned is the non-decorated type.

I'm running into this situation with a library I've written to decorate instances of an IConsumer.  Existing clients of this library currently have modules which first register everything by convention and then specific modules to override registrations with specific needs (e.g. other lifetime scope, custom factory logic, etc.)  The library works fine if the convention-based module is modified to have an exception for types implementing IConsumer, but I'd rather that this exception wouldn't need to be done as it's inconsistent with how other registrations are dealt with and it's just a hassle to debug if you forget or don't know to exclude the types prior to wiring up the decorators.

Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: I noticed you haven't seen any responses here. It might be good to put in some code snippets with a minimal example to help folks visualize what you're talking about... and possibly omitting things that don't pertain. For example, the whole "convention-based module registration" thing is interesting, it's what you're doing... but I'm not sure it's relevant to the question, so it gets confusing. Also, what have you tried? What hasn't worked? Have you tried [the latest decorator enhancements](https://alexmg.com/posts/upcoming-decorator-enhancements-in-autofac-4-9)?

Comment: (Instead of answering that in comments, please update the original question.)