# Can I override a list registration in StructureMap/Autofac?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, structuremap4

For overriding/replacing type registrations both frameworks use the "last registration wins". For collections (multiple implementations of the same interface) however, in both frameworks the collection is added to, never completely overridden/replaced with a new collection:

```
For<IService>().Use<Service1>();
For<IService>().Use<Service2>();
GetInstance<IEnumerable<IService>>() == IEnumerable[Service1, Service2]

// Overriding in child container/profile or Autofac tenant
For<IService>().Use<Service3>();
GetInstance<IEnumerable<IService>>() == IEnumerable[Service1, Service2, Service3]

// Even if I use StructureMap's ClearAll
For<IService>().ClearAll().Use<Service3>();
GetInstance<IEnumerable<IService>>() == IEnumerable[Service1, Service2, Service3]
```

My expectation is that I should be able to use something to clear or replace the parent registration when it comes to multiple implementations (i.e. collections) so that I can keep a separate list of a particular service in the parent/global and the child/tenant.

(I know StructureMap is no longer maintained and I'm willing to switch to another framework).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to remove registration from Autofac.

Anyway I can see 3 workarounds :

1. you can create a new `ContainerBuilder` and copy the required registration.

   See [Is it possible to remove an existing registration from Autofac container builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091101/is-it-possible-to-remove-an-existing-registration-from-autofac-container-builder)
2. You can register your own `IEnumerable<T>`

   ```
   builder.Register(c => new IService[] { c.Resolve<Service1>() })
          .As<IEnumerable<IService>>();
   ```
3. You can create your own `IRegistrationSource` for `IEnumerable<T>` and filter on the requested type

Answer (score 1):

[Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org) allows replacing the complete collection:

```cs
var container = new Container();

// Register NullLogger and SqlLogger as a collection of ILogger instances
container.Collection.Register<ILogger>(typeof(NullLogger), typeof(SqlLogger));

// Enable overriding registrations (without setting this, Simple Injector will throw)
container.Options.AllowOverridingRegistrations = true;

// Replace the complete collection of loggers with two different loggers
container.Collection.Register<ILogger>(typeof(ConsoleLogger), typeof(MailLogger));
```

Comment: Thank you Steven I actually started out with SI however in my project I need some form of child container or multitenancy support with an isolated scope (which to my knowledge isn't supported by SI) which is why I decided to try another framework. I really like SI's support for generics and the design decisions in general. I wasn't aware of the AllowOverridingRegistrations though, neat.